# Is there a maximum number of features allowed in R? Receiving "stack overflow" error message

Tags: python, r

Wondering if there is a capacity limit in R as to number of features? Trying to run different algorithms (elastic net, logistic regression, etc.) on a dataset with over 20,000 features. Encountering "stack overflow" error even on large server; wondering if this is due to capacity in R vs. hardware. Would Python be more appropriate?

Comment: stack overflow is more likely to be a problem with a deep recursion. Have you tested with a subset of features to see where your code breaks down?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.